# How to track failover email notification?

Tags: email, smtp, smtpclient

I am sending email from application. My problem is when your type email address means format is correct but it may be not available anywhere.so when I am trying send such email address using SMTP through application, so how to track fail-over notification if intended recipient not found.
please suggest any approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way of doing this. You *might* be able to make it work in some cases by parsing incoming email looking for delivery failure notices but it'll be a lot of work to keep that parsing code up to date. So at best you'll only get some of the notices. If you get a notice at all. The recipient's SMTP server may not send you anything, or the notice might get lost on it's way back to you.

The only way you are reliably get this sort of information is to host the SMTP server yourself, and deliver directly to the recipients SMTP server. In that case the SMTP server knows the status of the email's delivery and could report that to your email client via some non-standard back channel.

Note: Hosting your own SMTP server is non-trivial. And you will probably need to be on a fixed IP otherwise external SMTP servers will [treat your email as spam](https://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze/sending-from-dynamic-ip-address). In case you're thinking of running one over a home connection or something.